# Running a program that requires a password on the command line from a Perl script

Tags: perl, bash

I have written a Perl wrapper around a shell script. I am using IPC::Run::Simple to execute system commands.  As an example:

```
run ("mkdir ~$usr/12.2.0_cp/faiz_cpv/$pdate") or die "Error $ERR";
run ("cp ~$usr/12.2.0_cp/faiz_cpv/MPlist.lst ~$usr/12.2.0_cp/faiz_cpv/$pdate") || die "Error: $ERR";
run ("cd ~$usr/12.2.0_cp/faiz_cpv/$pdate; sh /opsutils/mfg_top/rel/CPV/bin/list_generation.sh . MPlist.lst mfg_relall_us\@oracle.com") or die "error $ERR";
.
.
```

One of these shell scripts requires the user of the script to enter their password. That is, a message is printed on stdout and the password is accepted via the shell. A number of calls are made to this shell script during the entire process which means a user must reenter his password a number of times.

Is there a way by which I can request user for the password at the command line itself, and pass that password implicitly instead of prompting user for the password again and again?

Comment: You should go for `IPC::Open3` or something similar as you basically need to use some two-way communication between your spawned commands and your script.

Comment: Perl has `mkdir` built in and [File::Copy](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Copy) provides a copy routine.  Its generally safer and faster to use them than shelling out.  Though it will not translate `~` for you.

Comment: You may need to investigate the [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect.pm) module if you really must run external programs that prompt you for passwords, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Perl has `mkdir` and `chdir` built in and [File::Copy](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aCopy) provides a copy routine.  Its generally safer and faster to use them than shelling out.  Though it will not translate `~` for you.  [File::chdir](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3achdir) makes changing a directory and running a command a little safer.

For the rest, use the full [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aRun) to control interacting with your program and [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](https://metacpan.org/module/Term%3a%3aReadLine%3a%3aGnu) to read the password without displaying it.  Sorry this is just a sketch and not a full answer.